# Windows 10 UWP app c# - Disable mouse wheel in combobox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

How is possible to disable mouse wheel in combobox control?

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ListDates" SelectedValuePath="Tag" Width="185" Background="#FFFFCC00" BorderThickness="1" Margin="12,8,0,0"/>
```

Comment: Why would you want to? It would just annoy your users that the mouse wheel isn't working. If you have a good reason to do this, tell us what it is.

Comment: If the combo box has focus and the mouse is over it, should not be able to be scrolled

Comment: Again, why should the user not be allowed to scroll it with the mouse wheel? Why force them to use the scrollbar or the keyboard? Are you sure you don't want to use [vertical scroll chaining](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.scrollviewer.isverticalscrollchainingenabled.aspx)?

Comment: I solved it by I set the focus by selecting another item

Comment: @KrisVandermotten because values could be accidentally changed while scrolling the page

Comment: If kendoo has the same problem as me, the problem is to disable scrolling with the mouse wheel _only_ when the combo is closed.

Answer (score 4):

This solution is verbose but works. Create your combobox class and override `OnPointerWheelChanged` with an empty handler.

```
public class ComboBoxNoWheel: ComboBox
{
    protected override void OnPointerWheelChanged(PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
}
```

You can add `e.handled = true` but it makes no difference from my tests. Scrolling when the combobox is open works fine.

Comment: In fact, there is an important difference when e.handled = true is present. If it is present, AND the pointer is over the ComboBox, the parent ScrollViewer doesn't receive the  PointerWheelChanged event. Thus, the scroll doesn't work. If e.handled = true is not present, the parent ScrollViewer does receive the event even though the pointer is over the ComboBox.

Answer (score 2):

If you must do that, it's pretty simple - just disable vertical scrolling on the inner ScrollViewer.

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ListDates" 
          ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollMode="Disabled"
```

Comment: No, I mean the scroll when the combo box has the focus and the mouse is over the combo box